# Using buffer-overflow to execute some simple instructions fail -- (segfaults)

Tags: c, mmap, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to buffer overflow and make the make the system execute `mmap` allocated address which would be a function of some simple instructions, namely

```
mov $0x1, %rax
ret
```

the opcode array for this is `\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc3`.

The following code I wrote

```
char shellcode[] = "\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc3";
int main() {
#define page 400
    char buff[page];
    
    void* m = mmap(NULL, 
            sizeof(shellcode),
            PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
            -1,
            0);

    for(int i=0;i<page;i++) strcat(buff, "\x90");
    strcat(buff, shellcode);
    strcpy(m,buff);
    int(*f)() = m;
    return f();
}
```

(my actual code is longer, so this is summary of what's being done there)

but when I run it, I get segfault

```
->  0x7ffff7ffa193: addl   %eax, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa195: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa197: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa199: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa19b: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa19d: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa19f: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1a1: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1a3: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1a5: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1a7: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1a9: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1ab: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1ad: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1af: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x7ffff7ffa1b1: addb   %al, (%rax)
```

but if I execute the follwing shellcode, `"\x32\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\x2b\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05\x05"`

it works as expected.

Please help me with how to make `"\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc3"` exeute.

Comment: It seems you do `strcat` into an uninitialized buffer, `buff`.

Comment: omitting `\x00`s and using `memcpy`, still segfaults.

Comment: What is the contents of the `m` buffer if you dump it out before call it?

Comment: can you explain how the `m` buffer is being dumped?

Comment: Which debugger do you use?

Comment: using the lldb debugger

Comment: I believe it's the `me` command in that.

Comment: @user1094822 If you manage to copy the byte code for `"mov $1, %rax; ret"` into the return address of main, what do you think that'll achieve? The ret instruction needs some code address to be at the top of the stack. You can be pretty sure there won't be one just underneath the one that main's return pops.

Comment: @user1094822 how did you make the shellcode? what is the full code? what arch, endian and cpu are you using? to me it also; looks like you're using att syntax is that correct?  Also how do you execute the shellcode?  and as someone has pointed out; there's a bad character that is '\x00'. And; lastly - it would be preferable to add tags, and references; and what debugger you use, (...) in the question :) and post some context/history/background, what is the purpose of the code? etc.

Comment: last comment question: what is the app (and most preferably, the app's `code`) you're trying to buffer overflow?  can you over write the registers (..) and so on ?

because it is a buffer overflow one has to know bad characters because **that will vary from app to app and system to system**